# Android close application on stand by

Tags: android

How can I close my application when the Android goes to stand by either by user pressing the button or screen timeout?
I've tried onResume(), onPause and onRestart() methods but I already use then in another context.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In your application class onCreate() method register receiver for Screen Off Event

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            Log.d(TAG, Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            Log.d(TAG, Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }
}, intentFilter);
```

like this.